# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/'

Tags: php-extension

I am getting this error log in my new dedicated server.

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/'

In php.ini

extensions =

extension_dir = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613

directory exists in the server but i cant understand why i am getting this ?

thx so much

Comment: Does the directory contain any extensions? Does PHP have the rights to read from it?

Comment: no there is nothing in directory :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the empty `extension=` line. Else PHP takes the right value (nothing) as a file name which obviously makes no sense.

If you want to load an extension you have to provide a filename to a `.so`/`.dynlib`/`.dll` file (depending on your system)